# All social share buttons (links) removing parameter after hash in URL

Tags: social-networking

I am having great trouble with sharing link which includes `#id` parameters in URL.

URL Example:

```
http://localhost/mysite/20/civitas-animum-genito-invenit-solutionem-ascendens-piratae?show=36#a36
```

So here all social channels posting URL before `#36`

```
http://localhost/q2a-16/20/civitas-animum-genito-invenit-solutionem-ascendens-piratae?show=36
```

This is very important since `#36` is a id of the sub-content (anchor jump)

All Sharing Links(buttons)

```
$this->output('<a class="btn btn-tweet" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="window.open(\'https://twitter.com/share?text='.$title.'&url='.$url.'&via=ME_HERE&wrap_links=true\', \'tweet\', \'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325,resizable=yes\');" ><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>');        
$this->output('<a class="btn btn-facebook" href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="window.open(\'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$url.'\', \'sharer\', \'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325,resizable=yes\');" target="_parent"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>');        

$this->output('<a class="btn btn-google" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$url.'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, \'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>');  

$this->output('<a class="btn btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.$url.'&title='.$title.'&summary='.$desc.'&source='.$url.'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, \'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>');
```

Any solution to get full URL including `#id`?

Comment: Solve the issue by using Google URL Shortener

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `%23` instead of `#`, It will work!

```
http://localhost/mysite/20/civitas...piratae?show=36%23a36
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue but forgot to update here. Sorry about that and thanks again for being helpful.

Comment: As of July 2015, this doesn't seem to work for me? I see the %23 printed out in my browser's URL bar, but I don't see it printed out in the actual input box in the share window.